# recursively loop over javascript object?

Tags: jquery, json, recursion, object

I am trying to create a function which,

When given an object will output something like

```
<div>
 reason : ok
 status : 0
 AiStatistics : null
 CurrentSeasonArenaStatistics : null
 <div>
  Player
  <div>
   CampaignProgressCoop : CompletedLegendary
   CampaignProgressSp : PartialHeroic
   <div>
    ReachEmblem
    <div>
     background_index : 2
     change_colors : [0,7,2,0]
     flags : 0
     foreground_index : 49
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
 gender : male
</div>
```

How would i go about this?

This is my attempt:

```
function read_object(object){
  var $obj = $('<div />');
  for(var o in object) {
    $obj.append(o+' : ');
    if(typeof(object[o]) == 'object' and object[o] != null) {
      $obj.append(read_object(object[o]));
    }
    else
      $obj.append(object[o]);
  }
  return $obj;
}
```

Here is the  object i am using

```
{
  "reason":"Okay",
  "status":0,
  "AiStatistics":null,
  "CurrentSeasonArenaStatistics":null,
  "Player":
  {
    "CampaignProgressCoop":"CompletedLegendary",
    "CampaignProgressSp":"PartialHeroic",
    "ReachEmblem":
    {
      "background_index":2,
      "change_colors":[0,7,2,0],
      "flags":0,
      "foreground_index":49
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I am not taking the piss.. but is it good practice to call your method from inside your method? Shouldn't it be its own method maybe to return a string for your output?

Comment: ok, fixed, issue was me having $obj and $obj2 instead of var $obj and var $obj2

Comment: That's the whole idea behind recursion Kieran. If you don't know the meaning of recursion yet, see the beginning of this sentence.

Comment: @Kieran
That is how recursion works.
You create something that just calls itself over and over again till it does not need to.

Comment: (looks up recursion...)cool recursion is pretty good.

Comment: FYI your object comparison uses the word "and" it should be &&. switching between python, apex, and javascript I had to pause for a couple minutes to adjust my brain to see it.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Separate the method out from the main call.

```
function read_object(object)
{
    //do some cool stuff to return a string
    return str;
}

function loopy(object)
{
    for(var o in object) 
    {
        if(typeof(object[o]) == 'object')
        {
            read_object(object)
        }
        else
        {
            //output in some other way
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: No matter what you do you would end up with a recursive pattern.

In your example you would just end up calling loopy from read_object.

Comment: Yeah totally this would only work for one level of DOM. I had a read of recursion. Most people say that you dont really need to use it and can cause stack problems however it does save on code